# OpenGL - Easiest way to draw a square with a texture

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

Usually I draw a square with a texture like this:

- Create a VBO with 4 coordinates (A,B,C,D for the square)
- Create a EBO with 4 indices (A,C,D and B,C,D) telling that I want to draw a square out of 2 triangles.
- Draw this elements with a texture

**Isn't there an easiest way without having a EBO array?**

Because it is not very handy to use... If I want to use like this:

VAO = [-0.8f, 0.5f, 0.0f, ...]

EBO = [0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...]

Then I need to remove a square from my VAO... then I also need to remove the indices from my EBO array and re-arrange it.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You did not specify the GL version you are targeting. Using the programmable pipeline, you can do this _attribute-less_, so the VBO and EBO both might be skipped completely. You still need to get the vertex data to shader, though (unless it is constant), but there are other possibilities nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't there an easiest way without having a EBO array?

Duplicate your vertices & use `glDrawArrays()`.

Comment: But that will give an overhead of 50% to the vertices right?

Comment: That's the trade-off, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you really only want to draw a square with a texture on it, you should consider make a new empty VAO, and just call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,3);`

The vertex shader then looks like this:

```
out vec2 mapping;

void main()
{
    float size = 1.0f;

    vec2 offset;
    switch(gl_VertexID)
    {
    case 0:
        //Bottom-left
        mapping = vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        offset = vec2(-size, -size);
        break;
    case 1:
        //Top-left
        mapping = vec2(0.0f, 1.0f);
        offset = vec2(-size, size);
        break;
    case 2:
        //Bottom-right
        mapping = vec2(1.0, 0.0);
        offset = vec2(size, -size);
        break;
    case 3:
        //Top-right
        mapping = vec2(1.0, 1.0);
        offset = vec2(size, size);
        break;
    }

     gl_Position = vec4(offset, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

The mapping variable tells the fragmentshader what the texture coordinates are.

Comment: This is my preferred way of rendering full-screen quads. But I would like to add that this could become a huge performance problem if you want to draw a large number of quads. The vertex shader does quite a lot of work per vertex, and it might even include branching depending on how clever the compiler is. Certainly fulfills the "easy" part of the question, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DrawArray to plot the indices.

Something like this:

```
Vertex2D* vertex = (Vertex2D*) vbo->lock();
        vertex[0].x = x[0]; vertex[0].y = y[0]; vertex[0].u = u[0]; vertex[0].v = v[0]; vertex[0].color = color;
        vertex[1].x = x[0]; vertex[1].y = y[1]; vertex[1].u = u[0]; vertex[1].v = v[1]; vertex[1].color = color;
        vertex[2].x = x[1]; vertex[2].y = y[1]; vertex[2].u = u[1]; vertex[2].v = v[1]; vertex[2].color = color;
        vertex[3].x = x[1]; vertex[3].y = y[0]; vertex[3].u = u[1]; vertex[3].v = v[0]; vertex[3].color = color;
vbo->unlock();

shader->bind();
vbo->bind();
vao->bind();
tex->bind();
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
tex->unbind();
vao->unbind();
vbo->unbind();
shader->unbind();
```